# Bottom a div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I haven't tried anything else except using vertical-align but it didn't do anything.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
   <div id="banner">
            <h2><span>HIGH QUALITY</span></h2>
            <h3>CRAFTMANSHIP AT LOW EVERYDAY PRICES</h3>
            <p>
            <a href="">LEARN MORE</a>
            <a href="">CALL US NOW</a>
            </p>
    </div>
 </html>

   <style>
        #banner {background-image: url(../images/common/banner.png);background-
         repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;font-family: 'Roboto 
         Slab',serif;color:#fff;height:730px;width: 1440px;}
        #banner {vertical-align: bottom;display:inline-block;vertical-align: 
         bottom;}
        #banner h2 span{background-image: 
         url(../images/common/orngebck.png);width:700px;padding:3px 120px 
         3px 120px;}
        #banner a{padding:11px 20px;margin:0px;border:1px solid #fff;display: 
         inline-block;vertical-align: bottom;}
        #banner a:hover{padding:11px 20px;margin:0px;border:1px solid 
         #F24134;background-color:#F24134;}
        #banner h2{font-size:3.125em;font-weight:100;}
        #banner h3{font-size:2.5em;font-weight:100;letter-spacing: 1px;}
   </style>
```

Here is the image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrCCN.jp]

What I want to achieve would look like this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ngde.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following structure:

```
<div id="outer-box">
    Normal text
    <div id="inner-box">
        Stuff that should be displayed at the bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use the following CSS to achieve what you want:

```
#outer-box {
    position:relative;
    /* your css code */
}

#inner-box {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px; /* distance from the bottom, you can use left, right and top as well */
    /* your css code */
}
```